# Merge two LLBLGEN 2 source files

Tags: merge, llblgenpro, llblgen

I have two LLGLGEN 2.6 pro source files that I have to merge in my git repo (2 different branches). Due to the "professionnal" work of previous programmers on this project, the two projects have changes (the fork is 1 year old) that are not tracked in documents.

What can be the less painfull solution to finalize my merge ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it's easier to simply ignore the merge conflicts in the LLBL generated code  and just re-sync the project to the database and then regenerate the code completely post-merge.

Where this becomes a problem is when there are a lot (or even a few) customizations made to the LLBL project file (e.g renaming fields, creating typed lists).  There isn't much you can do about these outside of tracking them down one by one.  The good news is the compiler will complain of something is missing or renamed.

Comment: There are many : typed lists, custom attributes... And these attributes are not seen by compiler... Do you think if I migrate both projects to llglben 4 I could better merge them ?

Comment: It seems likely that this would be easier, since LLBL used XML files for projects since v3.  I do not have first-hand experience with this type of conversion or merge, however.